# Read file, store content to an object, storing object in ArrayList causes java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am having some trouble to find out whats wrong with my code. I've been busy reading other topics with NullPointerExceptions and tried to find it out by using the debugger, I couldn't find a good video to show me how to work with a debugger so I kinda failed to figure it out.

I am using Netbeans and this is a take out from the error output:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tibianic.spy.system.FileHandler.addVipToList(FileHandler.java:81)
at tibianic.spy.system.FileHandler.loadVipList(FileHandler.java:65)
at tibianic.spy.system.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:27)
```

Im assuming the problem is located within the FileHandler Class - loadVipList/addVipToList methods.

The class:

```
package spy.system;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
*
* @author unknown
*/
public class FileHandler {
ArrayList<Vip> vip;

public FileHandler() {
    this.loadVipList();
}

public void setVipList(ArrayList<Vip> newList) {
    this.vip = newList;
}

public ArrayList<Vip> getVipList() {
    return this.vip;
}

public void saveVipList() {
    String line;
    try {
        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter("vip.txt");
        BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);

        for (Vip v : vip) {
            line = v.getName() + ":" + v.getNote();
            bWriter.write(line);
        }

        bWriter.close();
        fWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void loadVipList() {
    String line;
    String[] person;
    try {
        FileReader fReader = new FileReader("vip.txt");
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);

        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            person = line.split(":");
            addVipToList(person[0],person[1]);
        }

        bReader.close();
        fReader.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

private void addVipToList(String name, String note) {
    Vip guy = new Vip(name,note);
    vip.add(guy);
}
```

}

To my understanding the NullPointerException comes when im giving a object with value null to a method, is that right? I think there is a very small misstake I just cant find because I dont really know what the error message is trying to tell me -

I did cut out a header comment so the lines might not be accurate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is most likely that the `List` `vip` is `null` when `addVipToList` is called.  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Are you making sure you call setVipList before calling addVipToList ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception says that your error is located at `tibianic.spy.system.FileHandler.addVipToList(FileHandler.java:81)`

and based on your code it is thrown in the following method.

```
private void addVipToList(String name, String note) {
    Vip guy = new Vip(name,note);
    vip.add(guy);
}
```

Note that you have

```
public void setVipList(ArrayList<Vip> newList) {
    this.vip = newList;
}
```

you need to call setVipList() first before you call addVipToList(), since without that the list vip is still `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you never initialized the arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Vip> vip = new ArrayList<Vip>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't call setVipList() and I didn't want to call it - yet changing

```
public class FileHandler {
ArrayList<Vip> vip;
```

to

```
public class FileHandler {
ArrayList<Vip> vip = new ArrayList<>();
```

solved this, I knew this was easy - so embarrassing.

Well, thanks everyone for your fast responses.

Answer (score 0):

the class seems have problem:

when you new a instance ,it will be invoke method this.loadVipList();

```
public FileHandler() {
this.loadVipList();
}
```

but vip is null;

```
ArrayList<Vip> vip;
```

so you are better write like this:

```
ArrayList<Vip> vip = new ArrayList<Vip>();
```

or

```
List<Vip> vip = new ArrayList<Vip>();
```

it will be ok!